# Jquery preload event

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to run jquery function before page loads completely. Is there any way to do that in PHP/HTML ? I tried using -

```
$("document").ready(function()
{
   $(".colorClassT").addClass("bluet"); 
   $(".colorClassBg").addClass("bluebg");
});
```

Comment: Remove the document.ready and put the code right after the elements on the page or before the end of the page

Answer (score 0):

Just write the body of your function without the `$("document").ready(function()`.

The `$("document").ready(function()` says that whatever code is within that function will be executed only after the DOM have loaded completely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
window.onload = function(){     
 $(".colorClassT").addClass("bluet"); 
  $(".colorClassBg").addClass("bluebg");
 }
```

OR

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $(".colorClassT").addClass("bluet"); 
   $(".colorClassBg").addClass("bluebg");
});
```

`$(document).ready(function() {})` is jQuery event that is fired when DOM is loaded.

`$(window).load()` event is fired after whole content is loaded.